# Django database: how to filter objects based on other object's field?

Tags: python, django

In the code below, how do I filter `capital_listings` so to return listings only for capital cities? Also, is it possible to get rid of the intermediate `capitals_names` list?

```
capitals = City.objects.filter(status='capital')
capitals_names = [capital.name for capital in capitals]
capital_listings = Listing.objects.filter #???
```

Models:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = 'placeholder')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = 'placeholder')
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = 'placeholder')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `ForeignKey` here?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#relationships

Comment: @JonClements: No particular reason. How would I apply it in this case?

Comment: The Django tutorial is fairly good - if you have a look at the link that @HåkenLid posted above and the examples in it - that'll explain everything you need for it (and probably more that'll come in handy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `Listings.city` to a foreignkey relationship, you can do your query in a single step.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = 'placeholder')
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = 'placeholder')

class Listing(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


capital_listings = Listing.objects.filter(city__status='capital')
```

This is explained in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 2):

```
capital_listings = Listing.objects.filter(city__in=capital_names)
```